# Why does query execute on its own but not in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in the process of writing some stored procedures to transfer data from tables used for the current years records to tables used to store historical data. One example I am working on at present is a typical Master- Detail relationship, where the detail records obviously need to be processed before the master records.  I wrote a straightforward test query to collect some sample records and see if I had the basic sql correctly written.

```
DECLARE @cuttoffdate date = '31/03/2009'
SELECT
    *
FROM Landings.LandingDetails 
INNER JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders
    ON Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingId = Landings.LandingDetails.LandingId
WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cuttoffdate


SELECT
    *
FROM Landings.LandingHeaders

WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cuttoffdate
```

This works and produces two sets of records that I would expect.  However when I then use this in a stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [HistoricalData].[TransferAllLandingInformation] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@cutoffdate date
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO HistoricalData.HistoricalLandingDetails
        SELECT
            *
        FROM Landings.LandingDetails
        INNER JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders
            ON Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingId = Landings.LandingDetails.LandingId
        WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate


    INSERT INTO HistoricalData.HistoricalLandingHeaders
        SELECT
            *
        FROM Landings.LandingHeaders

        WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate
END
GO
```

it fails to execute giving me the following error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TransferAllLandingInformation, Line 12
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

line 12 being just after the BEGIN statement.

Could anyone enlighten me as to why this is happening.  I would by no means claim to be fluent in sql and as a result this particular error has me stumped at present and I would like to learn from it.

Just for the sake of clarity this is being written in SSMS 2012.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to Add into HistoricalLandingDetails all fields from FROM Landings.LandingDetails
        INNER JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders

Answer (score 4):

The error message indicates you have a differing number of columns in HistoricalLandingDetails to the results returned by your select query which has all the data from HistoricalLandingDetails and LandingHeaders.

I would recommend specifying columns in the insert and in the select to make sure everything matches up e.g.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [HistoricalData].[TransferAllLandingInformation] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@cutoffdate date
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO HistoricalData.HistoricalLandingDetails (cola, colb, colc)
        SELECT
            ld.cola, ld.colb, ld.colc
        FROM Landings.LandingDetails ld
        INNER JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders lh
...
```

Answer (score 2):

They don't have the same structure.

In query you are only selecting so those statement will work. However in procedure your insert statement fails.

The number of columns in the Target Table or number of columns specified in the Insert Statement and the Values supplied in the Insert statements are not matching.

Answer (score 1):

As error suggest you are trying to insert more values than column count in destination table. To fix that type explicitly column names eg:

```
INSERT INTO HistoricalData.HistoricalLandingHeaders (col1, col2)
SELECT Landings.LandingHeaders.val1, Landings.LandingHeaders.val2
FROM Landings.LandingHeaders
WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate
```